# Todo List for game design and development

Tags: xna

Is there and TODO list for a game design and development. I'm going to do a game in XNA and I would like to do my TODO list like:

1. Logo
2. Backgroud
3. Music

etc.

Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checklist for finished game? ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/checklist-for-finished-game)

Comment: Are you asking about bug/task tracking software?  Like http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/?

Comment: Are you asking how to develop your requirements (that is, how to decide what goes *on* the to-do list? Or are you asking for software to manage the to-do list?

Comment: I do not need tracking software or to-do list app. It's not big, just a WP7 XNA game. I want to make my TO-DO list for game like: background for the main sreen, background for another screen, hit sound for X. I dont want to forgot about important stuff. Just wondering if there is a blog where a guy post his TODO list for a game or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

As far as game design goes, you should start a wiki or document with your other collaborators and just keep adding to it. The new Google docs is really good for collaboration I find.

As well, try and "play the game in your head", and imagine how a player will interact with the finished product. Take note of everything. The user launches the game, what does he see? Is there an intro video? Can he hit a key to skip it? How does the screen transition from the intro video to the main menu? Is there an animation on the main menu, such as the game title scrolling into frame? Should there be? How does the user select a menu option? Does it play a sound effect when he does? etc. etc. etc. Just keep asking yourself questions from the user perspective throughout the development of the game.

Also, this article has some good things to check for regardless of platform: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/bestpractices_31

Comment: +1 for play your game in your head. Make sure you cover every scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://agilezen.com/